# SQL Query and Database Design

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I'm developing a backend for mobile application with Laravel Lumen and MYSQL as database for on demand delivery services, The simple idea of the app is the user creates a pickup request (which my have 1 order or multi orders and each order has its own drop off location) and the driver should track both pickup and drop off location on map.

Eventually I end up with pickups table which contain pickup province, pickup location, pickup time,..etc and orders table which contain pickup id as foreign key, drop off province, drop off locations, and other orders details.

Now to make it more clear :

```
1 pickup may have 1 order within, 
1 pickup may have 5 orders within
```

What i need is to get both pickup locations and drop off locations related to driver specific province in 1 query, is that possible ? and if not what is the best data base design to solve this issue.

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Presumably one order has one pickup and one drop off location?

Answer (score 0):

Presuming each order has one and only one pickup and drop off location, I would change your schema to have a single `locations` table.

```
locations
  id
  name
  address
  province
  ...etc...

orders
  id
  pickup_id references locations
  pickup_at
  dropoff_id references locations
  dropoff_at
  ...more info about the order...
```

You might need separate pickups and dropoffs tables, each which reference locations, but the important thing is to normalize locations into a single table and reference it.

Now we can connect orders to their locations. The basic query for orders and their pickup and dropoff locations is...

```
select ...
from orders o
join locations lp on lp.id = o.pickup_id
join locations ld on ld.id = o.dropoff_id
where ...
group by o.id;
```

We can use this to find orders which have either their pickup or drop off in a province.

```
select
  o.id,
  lp.name as pickup,
  lp.province as pickup_province,
  ld.name as dropoff,
  ld.province as dropoff_province
from orders o
join locations lp on lp.id = o.pickup_id
join locations ld on ld.id = o.dropoff_id
where ? in (lp.province, ld.province)
group by o.id;
```

Orders for a location.

```
select o.id, lp.name as pickup, ld.name as dropoff
from orders o
join locations lp on lp.id = o.pickup_id
join locations ld on ld.id = o.dropoff_id
where ? in (lp.name, ld.name)
group by o.id;
```

Orders entirely within one province.

```
select o.id, ld.province as province
from orders o
join locations lp on o.pickup_id = lp.id
join locations ld on o.dropoff_id = ld.id
where lp.province = ld.province
group by o.id
```

And more.

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=633b0ab981b0361ddca111a5d8dc732a)

Comment: @Schwen Thanks for your reply, but my main problem is in the situation when the user pickup may have more than one order and each has its own province and location and in this case how i can get 1 drop off location and several drop off location in one query to show it on map for the driver

Comment: @AliAdil Sorry, I don't understand. Do you mean when one delivery person has been assigned multiple orders and you want to get all the pickup and drop off locations for their orders? Could you give a concrete example?

Comment: @Schwen Some times the request of pickup came from stores which have multi customers orders so in this case the pickup location will be one and the delivery location will by many, but i think your previous design will solve the issue Im still trying